# Lisp and Android NDK

Tags: c++, android, lisp, android-ndk

Is there a lisp ported to android with the NDK? I've been thinking of writing one in C++, for a project I have going, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Has anyone seen such a beast?

I have seen [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) project, but it's not quite what I'm looking for...

Comment: I would love to try porting Chibi Scheme to the NDK, but it's a matter of Copious Free Time. ;-)

Comment: Well, I've played around with Lisp under C++ before, and since the NDK allows me to compile those, I think it won't be *too* much trouble to put together initially. I just don't want to do it if someone else is already working on a similar project, as I could just contribute there.

Comment: How about a bracketed version of Python? That would be pretty close to lisp :)

Comment: @Larry: Only if it has real macros, continuations, first-class functions (not the kind of neutered lambdas Python provides), proper tail calls, etc. ;-)

Comment: There also appears to be [Moby](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/package-source/dyoo/moby.plt/3/9/planet-docs/manual/index.html) Scheme for android as well, but that compiles to Javascript, not even bytecode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There is an effort underway to run [ECL on Android with the NDK](https://github.com/ageneau/ecl-android).**

[Embeddable Common Lisp](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) (ECL) is an implementation of Common Lisp that compiles to C.

According to a recent [post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.ecl.general/8306) from the developer about the status of ECL on Android, "it's now at a point where it's reasonably complete." The developer is currently working on adding bindings to the java API.

Comment: I wish I could give the credit to both of you for this answer! Both variants of Lisp appear reasonably complete for my purposes. I'll see what I can do to help finish both up. Thanks again!

Comment: To honor your intention of giving credit to both of us, I've upvoted the answer of wm_eddie.

Answer (score 9):

I hate answers that just have a link but I came across this blog post of a guy who got Gambit Scheme running:

http://seanchapel.blogspot.com/2010/10/gambit-scheme-on-android.html

From the comments it looks like this blog post was discussed on the Mailing list, so it might be possible to build it without patching now.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about NDK lisps, but there is at least [a port of clojure for Dalvik](https://github.com/remvee/clj-android) (so not NDK) but it is right now pretty much too slow to load to be really useful. Apparently, there is some focus to improve load time on android.

Other refs: http://www.deepbluelambda.org/programming/clojure/creating-android-applications-with-clojure

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but one of the reasons I'm looking to do this in the NDK is because all of the current implementations of Lisp under the JVM have such poor performance. I'm hoping that that changes in the future, however.

Comment: I understand your point. Just wanted to point out one of the possible alternatives if there isn't a portable non-Dalvik lisp for android. I'm certainly interested if there are any.